# How to require/read the JSON files from aws-sdk apis folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to fetch all the instance types for EC2 from [EC2 SDK JSON](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/apis/ec2-2016-11-15.normal.json)

```
const instanceEnums = require('aws-sdk/apis/ec2-2016-11-15.normal.json');

function getAllTypes(property) {
   return instanceEnums.shapes[property].enum;
}
getAllTypes('InstanceType')
```

But It throws an error that

> cannot find module aws-sdk/apis/ec2-2016-11-15.normal.json

I realized that the installed SDK/module does not include the .normal.json file but only .min.js file.

Is there any other way to access the files from `apis` folder same as we can access `clients` folder just by requiring SDK and `AWS.EC2` and all(as sdk exports the `clients` folder's files from index.js.)

I need to use something like explained as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42494509/9381809

Comment: Probably, you might have to do some workaround until the feature is implemented. check [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/630) github issue.

Comment: ahh! thanks @Imran, I hope they implement the feature in JavaScript sdk as well. however seems I will have to go with workaround suggested in issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download `ec2-2016-11-15.normal.json` directly from github (on the application startup for example) and use it like as follows:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/master/apis/ec2-2016-11-15.normal.json';

const getAllTypes = (() => {
  const loadApi = axios.get(url);
  return (property) => loadApi.then(response => {
    return response.data.shapes[property].enum
  })
})();

getAllTypes('InstanceType').then((types) => {
  console.log(types);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I guess this is the only way to go ahead for now.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me.

```
const instanceEnums = require('aws-sdk/apis/ec2-2016-11-15.min.json');
console.log(instanceEnums.shapes);
```

Comment: `shapes` is one of the four objects which is not even minified however shapes has 40 inner objects whose names are minified to (S3, S7, S.. etc) and I need `intanceType`

Comment: Gotcha.  Do you have a hard dependency on the AWS SDK for this?  I found this on GitHub which looks like it's up to date at first glance.

Comment: I just need all the EC2 instance types not only available but all existing, I just don't want to hardcode this data as this may get appended, If I can get the data from somewhere else that also works. I already have SDK in my modules so wanted to use the same but not mandatorily need to use SDK.